# Failing to run a training job in SageMaker - Unknown parameter in input: "ProfilerRuleConfigurations"

Tags: boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I tried to run a training job with the latest SageMaker SDK (2.24.5) in a clean virtual environment and am getting the error:

> botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
> Unknown parameter in input: "ProfilerRuleConfigurations", must be one
> of: TrainingJobName, HyperParameters, AlgorithmSpecification, RoleArn,
> InputDataConfig, OutputDataConfig, ResourceConfig, VpcConfig,
> StoppingCondition, Tags, EnableNetworkIsolation,
> EnableInterContainerTrafficEncryption, EnableManagedSpotTraining,
> CheckpointConfig, DebugHookConfig, DebugRuleConfigurations,
> TensorBoardOutputConfig, ExperimentConfig, ProfilerConfig

Answer (score 2):

this issue sometimes occurs because a much older botocore version was first installed and old botocore models (where ProfilerRuleConfigurations is not defined) is cached somewhere, even if a new botocore version is installed. This caching doesn’t appear to be tied with the package itself, hence why setting up a new virtual environement doesn’t always fix the issue.

Check to see if a folder ~/.aws/models exists, and if it does, remove the folder and start a new virtual environment.

```
mv  ~/.aws/models /tmp
```